# Finding the sixth roots of $-8i$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So to find the sixth roots of $-8i$, it would be equivalent to:
$$z^6=-8i$$
So after all the math work, I end up getting my final answer to be:
$$\sqrt2 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right)$$

$$=\sqrt2 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right)$$

Where I found $\theta$ to be $3\pi/2$ and $n=6$. Then plugging in.

$$=\sqrt2 \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{3\pi/2+2\pi k}{6}\right) ;k=0,1,2,3,4,5.$$

So my question is, is everything I did so far correct?
And to finish off, I would just plug in values for k and simply to get all the sixth roots of -8i correct?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What means "cis"?

Comment: cis being the short form for $r[cos\theta + isin\theta]$

Comment: Actually, $\operatorname{cis}\theta=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Comment: OK, thx. Why don't writing $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @Léo Because that is cumbersome when $\theta$ is a complicated expression. Though you *could* use $\exp(i\theta)$ instead.

Comment: @Léo This is the short way to write out the expression instead of writing out terms in exponent.

Comment: user136088, you need to determine the principal argument of $-8i$.  $3\pi/2$ is not the principal argument.

Comment: $\operatorname{cis}\theta$ has an advantage over $e^{i\theta}$ in some contexts, specifically when one wishes to avoid mentioning that it's an exponential function.  That is useful when you're going through a proof or a heuristic or intuitive argument that -- lo and behold -- it unexpectedly turns out to be an exponential function.  It would be not just silly but confusing to say to a class "$x\mapsto a^x$ doesn't _look_ like an exponential function but we will show that, surprisingly, that's what it is."

Comment: @NasuSama Why is that necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you advance

> $$ z^6=-8i = 8 e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2}}=8 e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2}+2k\pi i}\implies z= 8^{1/6} e^{-\frac{\pi i}{12}+\frac{k\pi i}{3}},\quad k=0,1,2,3,4,5. $$

Comment: Is this not essentially what I have?

Comment: @user136088 Yes.